# Merge record into ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I pull a record as:

```
def self.imp_broadcast_preview!
  Broadcast.where(for_gamers: true).order(:created_at).last
end
```

And then in my controller I have:

```
def index
  @conversations = Conversation.where(gamer: @gamer)
  @conversations << Broadcast.imp_broadcast_preview!
end
```

The above code works properly in `Rails 4.2` and merges the last broadcast message in the conversations. I just updated my codebase to `Rails 5.2` and now I am getting an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for #<Conversation::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fd2541baca0>)
```

I tried using `merge` instead but that throws an error as well since `broadcast` is not an `activerecord relation`

Comment: Indeed, that's not possible anymore. I could search for the PR in the Rails repo, but it'll take some time. Try adding `.to_a` in the first line `@conversations = Conversation.where(gamer: @gamer).to_a`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @fanta Yeah, that works perfectly. Thank you! If you add this as an answer then I will definitely accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality got removed in rails 5.0, you can check https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25906. There you'll find why it was removed, and the link to the commit that removed that functionality.

To make your code work, what you should do is to convert to an Array your first result, that way `<<` will work:

```
def index
  @conversations = Conversation.where(gamer: @gamer).to_a
  @conversations << Broadcast.imp_broadcast_preview!
end
```