# How to push an object into ActiveRecord::Relation in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am stuck in weird situtaion, I am working on upgrading an existing rails 3 appliction to rails 5 app.

Using rails 3, I have an object report which has many organizations

```
@report.organizations
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Organization id: 1, name: "Org 1", description: nil, created_at: "2012-01-27", updated_at: "2019-01-15">]>
@report.organizations.count    # 1
```

when I push a new org object into existing activerecord relation it gives me new activerecord relation including new org

```
@report.organizations<< Organization.new
[#<Organization id: 1, name: "Org 1", description: nil, created_at: "2012-01-27", updated_at: "2019-01-15">, #<Organization id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
# Getting count
@report.organizations.count    # 2
```

Using rails 5, I am getting exception

```
@report.organizations << Organization.new
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `<<' for #<Organization::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f93483e2640>
```

and when I do like

```
@report.organizations.to_a << Organization.new
```

it gives me

```
[#<Organization id: 1, name: "Org 1", description: nil, created_at: "2012-01-27", updated_at: "2019-01-15">, #<Organization id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

but count is stil 1 instead of two

```
@report.organizations.count    # 1
```

Hope my issue is clear to you, please help me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: will you save this record later ?

Comment: if no , directroly use  `@report.organizations.count + 1`

Comment: Do you get same error for rails-4 also?

Comment: Why it shows like `#<Organization::ActiveRecord_Relation` instead of  
 `Organization::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`

Comment: Not sure why may be in rails 5 it is like that only, also i didn't checked in rails 4 because I am upgrading from rails 3 to rails 5 directly :-)

Comment: Well, I had done this for big project but we did as `rails-3 -> rails-4` first then `rails-4 -> rails-5` to keep track.

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891347/merge-record-into-activerecord-relation#comment94629803_53891347, you'll also find the code in which this was removed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) it should work. If it doesn't, try using `create`:

```
 @report.organizations.create
```

Comment: for some reason, I don't want to create new organization instead I need to push new org in activerecord relation without creating

Comment: If the count was changed in Rails 4, you were effectively creating a new org

Comment: Since this is simply a class and not extended by activerecord base class, `organziations` is an attribute_reader in report class whose value is calculated by finding `org` from database.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using new definetly u need to save that variable 
For example

```
organization=Organization.new
organization.name = "organization 1"
organization.description= "Something description"
organization.save #save the array obj
Organization.count #1
```

else use create method to create the record Suddenly both are same

```
Organization.create(name:"org2",description: "something")
Organization.count #2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
a=[]
a << @report.organizations
a.count # => 1
a << Organization.new
a.count # => 2
```

Comment: a = [] is not `a = Organization.none`

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
@report_data = @report.organizations
@report_data.count # => 1
@report_data += [Organization.new]
@report_data.count # => 2
```